# Carousel in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, extjs

How can I add carousel in tabbar in phone gap?

```
items : [ {
                title : 'User',  
                html : '<h2>User Card</h2>',
                cls : 'card5',  
                iconCls : 'user'
            }, {
                title : 'User',
                html : '<h1>User Card</h1>',
                cls : 'card5',
                iconCls : 'user'
            }, {
                title : 'User',
                html : '<h1>User Card</h1>',
                cls : 'card5',
                iconCls : 'user',

            } ]
```

I have to add carousel in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out the answer

```
items : [ {
            title : 'User',  
            html : '<h2>User Card</h2>',
            cls : 'card5',  
            iconCls : 'user'
        }, myCarousel, {
            title : 'User',
            html : '<h1>User Card</h1>',
            cls : 'card5',
            iconCls : 'user',

        } ]
```

where myCarousel will be the object of Carousel